# How to avoid overlaying shadow in one side in CSS3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to set shadow effect for a content and i can be able to set it. But i overlays with adjacent element which disturbs the look. Is there any possible way to remove the overlaying effect for specific area(in the red circle in image)? Pleas check the sample image below.

[image: sample image]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="table1">
        <table>
            <tr><td>AAA</td></tr>
            <tr><td>BBB</td></tr>
            <tr><td>CCC</td></tr>            
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="table2"  class="Shadow">
        <table>
            <tr><td>aaa</td><td>eee</td></tr>
            <tr><td>bbb</td><td>fff</td></tr>
            <tr><td>ccc</td><td>ggg</td></tr>
            <tr><td>ddd</td><td>hhh</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {    
    position: relative;
}
table,td,tr{
    border:1px solid black;
}
#table1{    
    position: absolute;     
}
#table2{    
    position:absolute;
    background-color:pink;
    margin-left:40px;
}
.Shadow{
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px 9px #476FCC;
box-shadow: 0 0 30px 9px #476FCC;
}
```

JS Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/5JYPm/13/

Comment: you mean you want to remove the shadow in the red circle?

Comment: @RanjithKumarGovarthanan - can't be done. You can, however, position the element that is behind the shadow so that it is ON TOP of the shadow. Will that satisfy your requirement?

Comment: @Adam: Yeah.. i think it can satisfy my requirement. Thanks.

Comment: Then here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/W7vjX/. It's your exact fiddle except with a background color of #fff added to the first table and a z-index added.

Answer (score 3):

I think the closest you are going to get is stacking the first table over the second, and ensuring you have a background colour on it:

```
#table1{    
    position: absolute;     
    z-index:2;
    background-color:#fff;
}
#table2{    
    position:absolute;
    background-color:pink;
    margin-left:40px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5JYPm/16/

Answer (score 3):

you need to change the `z-index`s  of the tables and then add a background-color to table1

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/5JYPm/17/)

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the box-shadow to the right about half the spread?

```
.Shadow{
box-shadow: 15px 0 30px 0px #476FCC;
}
```

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/tR2S4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="table2" style="z-index:-1;" class="shadow">
```